# Who took care of Teddy?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* we are informed that Remus Lupin and Tonks have a child.

> However, both Remus and Tonks die leaving Teddy without parents.

In light of this - who ultimately takes care of Teddy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nymphadora Tonk's mom (Teddy's Grandmother on mother's side) [Andromeda Tonks](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Andromeda_Tonks).

From [2007/07/30 Bloomsbury Chat with JKR:](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html)

> **Tineke**: Did teddy grow up living with his grandmother?
>   **JKR**: **Yes, Teddy was raised by Andromeda.**
>   **JKR**: However, unlike Neville, who was also raised by his grandmother
>   **JKR**: Teddy had his godfather, Harry, and all his father's friends in the Order, to visit and stay with.